# R glm.predict cannot be found

Tags: glm

I am not sure what to do when R tells me it can't find a package that has been installed.  Any suggestions?

```
model1 = glm( RESPONSE ~ AGE + as.factor(SEX) + SYSBP + 
             as.factor(DIABETES) + LDLC + as.factor(BPMEDS) + 
             as.factor(CURSMOKE) + HDLC + HEARTRTE + TIME, 
             data=trVal, family=binomial(link=logit))

glm.predict has been installed successfully
library(glm.predict)
glm.predict(model1)
Error: could not find function "glm.predict"
```

Answer (score 1):

`glm.predict` is the package's name, not a function. What you are looking for is probably the function `discrete.changes()` from the `glm.predict` package.